# add path directories for boost installation

Tags: software-installation, shared-library, paths

I have installed boost_1.58_0 on my loptop's home directory. After some processes I faced to this message:

```
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

/home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

/home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib
```

However for other boost versions I have seen some posts but unfortunately I am not able to use of them. Regarding to my low knowledge in ubuntu, I think they are not so straightforward and clear.

The bellow lines related to the comment

```
 # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
 # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package    bash-doc)
# for examples

 # If not running interactively, don't do anything
 case $- in
 *i*) ;;
  *) return;;
esac

    # don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the     history.
   # See bash(1) for more options
   HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

 # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
  shopt -s histappend

  # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in    bash(1)
    HISTSIZE=1000
    HISTFILESIZE=2000

     # check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
      # update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
    shopt -s checkwinsize

    # If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
   # match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
   #shopt -s globstar
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to build *with* boost, and how (`make`? `cmake`?) Fundamentally you will need to add directives like `-I /home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58_0` and `-L /home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib` on the compiler/linker command lines, however the easiest way to do that will depend somewhat on the build environment you're using.

Comment: @steeldriver, I had used (before I asked my question here) this line:         env CPPFLAGS='-I/home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58_0' LDFLAGS='-L/home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib' ./configure     but it did not help me

Comment: Also, after using of Wayne_Yux answer, I checked in terminal with `acerv3-571g@acerv3571g-Aspire-V3-571G:~$ dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp` , But I just had gotten :                                                           `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/include/boost/version.hpp`
`

Comment: `dpkg` won't know anything about software that you have installed manually. If `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` dont' work, try running `./configure --help` and looking for variables related specifically to the boost library such as `--with-boost=`. If you need further help then tell us what you're trying to build.

Comment: I installed the boost_1_58 for building ALPS code, but the main problem happened with this message:                   from /home/acerv3-571g/Downloads/alps-2.2.b3-r7462-src-with-boost/boost/libs/mpi/src/broadcast.cpp:9:
/home/acerv3-571g/Downloads/alps-2.2.b3-r7462-src-with-boost/boost/boost/mpi/config.hpp:20:17: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mpi.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: That error looks like it is related to the MPI library - not the boost libraries. BTW what Ubuntu version are you using? why are you even using the `...-src-with-boost` version? I just downloaded the regular alps-2.2.b3-r7462-src.tar.gz and `cmake` seems quite happy to use boost-1.54 from the Trusty repository.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for following my question. Thank you very much. and exuse me for my stupid questions.  Do you mean that I must use alps-2.2.b3-r7462-src.tar.gz instead of  alps-2.1.1-r6176-src-with-boost.tar.gz, because I have installed boost myself? and for the command `cmake -D Boost_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/path/to/boost/directory /path/to/alps/directory`  I must write: `cmake -D Boost_ROOT_DIR:PATH=/home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58  /home/acerv3-571g/Downloads/alps-2.2.b3-r7462/alps`

Comment: At this point, I think you would be better asking a new question such as "How do I install ALPS (Algorithms and Libraries for Physics Simulations) 2.2.b3 on Ubuntu X.Y" where X.Y is your actual release version.

Comment: Ok, I will do your advice. I should collect my question and ask that.

Answer (score 1):

you need the following commands:

```
export INCLUDE="/home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58_0:$INCLUDE"
export LIBRARY_PATH="/home/acerv3-571g/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH"
```

you can execute them in a terminal to set these variables in the current terminal session. If you want to make them permanent, you have to add these lines to your `.bashrc`

Comment: Thank so much for your guidance, I went to home directory and use of ` ls -la ~/ | more` to see hiddens, After that I used of emacs to edit the .bashrc but As I uploud that in the main question, I do not know where I should add those line in the file?!

Comment: you can just add them at the end of the file